# Нестандартные тонкости русского языка

Tags: общие-вопросы

Как называется жест, показанный И. Андерсоном на обложке пластинки 1976 года "[Too Old to Rock ’n’ Roll: Too Young to Die!](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Too_Old_to_Rock_%E2%80%99n%E2%80%99_Roll:_Too_Young_to_Die)". В смысле литературное название.

[image: Too_Old_to_Rock_'n'_Roll_Too_Young_to_Die!]

Answer (score 1):

Устоявшегося литературному обозначения у неприличного жеста быть не может. В Википедии статья про него называется "Жест по локоть". У меня к этому  жесту ассоциация со фразой "На тебе колокольню Ивана Великого", но откуда взялась эта ассоциация вспомнить не могу.

Comment: Насчет "колокольни" даже всезнающему интернету неизвестно, а по поводу  "Жест по локоть" - интересные сведения. Думаю, не все у нас знают, что жест - международный.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно сослаться на этот жест, можно указать его значение как "вот вам всем" - знакомые с этим жестом его распознают. У Андерсона он мог конкретно означать "не дождётесь".

Comment: "Вот вам всем" - если картинка не сопровождает текст, многие не поймут, о чем речь.

Comment: Не думаю, что кому-либо при этих словах придёт в голову другой жест: обычный кукиш - обращение индивидуальное.